# ValueError: x, y, and format string must not be None taylor sine

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math, taylor-series

I'm about to approximate sine with a taylorseries and plot different iterations in comparrison with the real sine. Does anybody know where i made a mistake?

```
%pylab inline
from math import factorial as fak

def taylor_sinus(n,x):
    if n==1:
        sinx=x
    elif n < 1:
        print('ERROR 302: approximation not found')
    else:
        sinx=0
        for i in range(1,n):
            sinx=sinx-((-1)**i*((x**(2*i-1))/fak(2*i-1)))
        return(sinx)


x=np.linspace((-2*pi), (2*pi), 100)
iterations=(1,3,8,11,)

for iteration in (iterations):
    plt.plot(x, taylor_sinus(iteration,x), label='Iterationen: {0}'.format(iteration))
plt.plot(x, sin(x), ':', lw=4, label='The one and only Sinus')

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('f(x)')
plt.ylim(-2,2)
plt.grid()
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are ther useful information.

Comment: you may have wrong indentation and `return(sinx)` is inside `else` - so for `n==1` it returns `None` - and this makes problem to display it and you get your error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong indentation and `return(sinx)` is inside `else` - and for `n==1` it returns `None`

So change indentation

```
def taylor_sinus(n,x):
    if n==1:
        sinx=x
    elif n < 1:
        print('ERROR 302: approximation not found')
    else:
        sinx=0
        for i in range(1,n):
            sinx=sinx-((-1)**i*((x**(2*i-1))/fak(2*i-1)))
    return(sinx)
```

or add `return(sinx)` for `n==1`

```
def taylor_sinus(n,x):
    if n==1:
        sinx=x
        return(sinx)
    elif n < 1:
        print('ERROR 302: approximation not found')
    else:
        sinx=0
        for i in range(1,n):
            sinx=sinx-((-1)**i*((x**(2*i-1))/fak(2*i-1)))
        return(sinx)
```